# Change color of specific tiles in SKTileMapNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

I am creating a round based game where I have a playground as a SKTileMapNode with grass textures on every tile where characters can walk from tile to tile. Every character has his own reach where they can walk in one round. I want to display this range so that the player can see the range of the selected character. My question: How can I change the color of those tiles which are in the range of the tile where a specific character is on? SKSpriteNode with textures can simply change their color by `.color` and `.colorBlendFactor` so that my green grass texture gets for example a red touch. How am I able to do this with specific tiles in a SKTileMapNode?

Answer (score 0):

```
let tile = tileMap.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row)
```

Once you have the tile you can modify the textures of the tile `tile.textures` to either include tinted textures or draw the colored textures yourself (messy but here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751294/programmatically-creating-an-sktiledefinition) of that).

I would recommend a different approach though of getting the center of the tiles `tileMap.centerOfTile(atColumn: column, row: row)` you'd like to color and using this and their size `tileMap.tileSize` to create nodes `SKSpriteNode` above the tiles you'd like to be colored.

Comment: How are you going to select a particular tile, then?

Comment: You should read my question again. As @ElTomato already asked, the task is to change the color of specific tiles, not the whole tile map node

Comment: My apologizes, I did not fully read the question, hopefully my edit helps.

Comment: I also had both ideas, but having every texture in a colored version isn't a nice solution as you already mentioned. Also I wanted to avoid creating SKSpriteNode for specific tiles since a SKTileMapNode itself is like an Array of SKSpriteNodes in one node, but from my knowledge without the same supporting functions/attributes as in SKSpriteNode for the single tiles inside a map. Thanks for your contribution